# Archbang can't connect to wireless

Tags: wifi, drivers, archbang

Last week I tried Crunchbang 11, it couldn't connect to wireless. Yesterday I removed it and installed Archbang from CD (final 2012 version). Everything was working perfectly, when I did `pacman -Syu` and rebooted, Archbang stopped detecting my wireless card so I bet that the new Linux drivers aren't compatible with my HP Pavillion G. It's not the first time that I've seen drivers incompatible with my laptop, I've seen it last week with Crunchbang, and I've had graphics issues with every Linux that i've used on this laptop.

What I would like to do is simple. I want to downgrade the Archbang wireless drivers, I want my original drivers back, the ones installed in the final 2012 version (I have the CD, can I use it?), and then I don't want to allow pacman to upgrade my wireless drivers, so next time I run `pacman -Syu`, I want everything to be upgraded except my wireless drivers, and if possible my graphic card drivers.

You see Ubuntu 12.04 works great, 12.10 doesn't work at all, I don't even see the login screen, even with `nomodeset`. I don't want that to happen, and Archbang is a rolling release so I don't know if the next time I upgrade my packages I'll face some issues, I want to allow pacman to upgrade everything, just don't mess with my graphics and my wireless, that's it.

Comment: If you don't want to update the drivers, keep in mind you also don't want to update the kernel.

Comment: @goldilocks can't i just tell pacman to exclude any update related to my graphic drivers and my wireless card? for example i would like to upgrade openbox, firefox, my sound drivers, fix any security issue with the kernel, just not my graphic card and my wireless

Comment: The drivers are part of the kernel.  If the drivers have broken recently, they are broken for that kernel version.  So you have to rollback to a previous kernel where the drivers worked.

Comment: @goldilocks fine, i'll remove archbang, i don't have any other choice, i was so so happy to install it yesterday, only to remove it today, what a short love story :) one day marriage only happens in Hollywood and in the pc world :P